# Find and replace text with an image in Word document

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I have figured out how to replace words in documents as this is fairly easy using the find object. Now I am struggling with replacing the word "*logo*" with an actual logo image throughout a word document.

I figured I can loop through each Range in the document and say that if the word *logo* is found  in the range, I can add a picture doing:

```
foreach (Range rngStory in doc.StoryRanges)
{                
    rngStory.InlineShapes.AddPicture(filename);
}
```

The problem is that this will add the picture to the top of the range and not exactly where the text logo is.

Does anyone have a good solution for doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.inlineshapes.addpicture%28v=office.11%29.aspx

See the optional Range parameter

> Range
>
> Optional Object. The location where the picture will be placed
> in the text. If the range isn't collapsed, the picture replaces the
> range; otherwise, the picture is inserted. If this argument is
> omitted, the picture is placed automatically.

So I would say you query for the current position where you have you *logo* tag, and use that as the Range value.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like in the case of my loop, a Range is actually a pretty big chunck of text in the document - adding the picture to the Range is just putting it before all the text - I guess would I need is to specify the range better somehow?

Comment: When you AddPicture it returns a Shape, see this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.shape%28v=office.11%29.aspx), and read the explanation for the 'RelativeHorizontalPosition' and 'RelativeVerticalPosition' properties

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by following way: This Code replaces text to image at the accurate position.

```
      Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref outputFile, ref oMissing,
                     ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                     ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                     ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                doc.Activate();
              try
                {
                    //----------------------Replace--------------------------------
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find fnd = wordApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find;
                    fnd.ClearFormatting();
                    fnd.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
                    fnd.Forward = true;
                    fnd.Wrap = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;

    string imagePath = Server.MapPath("~/data/uploads/violations/resize/Image.jpg");
    var keyword = "LOGO";
                        var sel = wordApp.Selection;
                        sel.Find.Text = string.Format("[{0}]", keyword);
    wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(keyword);

                        Word.Range range = wordApp.Selection.Range;
     if (range.Text.Contains(keyword))
                            {
                                //gets desired range here it gets last character to make superscript in range 
                                Word.Range temprange = doc.Range(range.End - 4, range.End);//keyword is of 4 charecter range.End - 4
                                temprange.Select();
                                Word.Selection currentSelection = wordApp.Selection;
                                //currentSelection.Font.Superscript = 1;

                                sel.Find.Execute(Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceOne);
                                sel.Range.Select();
                                var imagePath1 = Path.GetFullPath(string.Format(imagePath, keyword));
                                sel.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName: imagePath1, LinkToFile: false, SaveWithDocument: true);
     }
}
catch { }
            finally
            {
                if (doc != null)
                {
                    ((_Document)doc).Close(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(doc);
                }
                if (wordApp != null)
                {
                    ((_Application)wordApp).Quit();
                    Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wordApp);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in this way: This replaces text to image on the top of the document

```
  Word.Application wordApp = new Word.Application();
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref outputFile, ref oMissing,
                 ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                 ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                 ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
            doc.Activate();
          try
            {
                //----------------------Replace--------------------------------
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find fnd = wordApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.Find;
                fnd.ClearFormatting();
                fnd.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
                fnd.Forward = true;
                fnd.Wrap = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;

string imagePath = Server.MapPath("~/data/uploads/violations/resize/Image.jpg");
var keyword = "LOGO";
                    var sel = wordApp.Selection;
                    sel.Find.Text = string.Format("[{0}]", keyword);
wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(keyword);

                    Word.Range range = wordApp.Selection.Range;


                            sel.Find.Execute(Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceOne);
                            sel.Range.Select();
                            var imagePath1 = Path.GetFullPath(string.Format(imagePath, keyword));
                            sel.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName: imagePath1, LinkToFile: false, SaveWithDocument: true);




  }
  catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            if (doc != null)
            {
                ((_Document)doc).Close(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(doc);
            }
            if (wordApp != null)
            {
                ((_Application)wordApp).Quit();
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wordApp);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var wApp = new Application();
var wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(Path.GetFullPath(filePath), ReadOnly: false);
imagePath = Path.GetFullPath(imagePath);

foreach (Range rng in wDoc.StoryRanges)
    while (rng.Find.Execute(keyword, Forward: true, Wrap: WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue))
    {
        rng.Select();
        wApp.Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture(imagePath, false, true);
    }
```

Comment: While code only answers are allowed, please consider adding some description. This will allow the answer to be more widely understandable.