# Replace Text With Image Word

Tags: c#, .net, docx

i want text tag with an image

```
var doc = DocX.Load("C:\\tm.docx");
        doc.ReplaceText("##Date_Date##", Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today), false);
        doc.ReplaceText("##text##", richTextBox1.Text, false);
        doc.ReplaceText("##number##", textBox1.Text, false);
        doc.ReplaceText("##User_name##", textBox3.Text, false);
        doc.ReplaceText("##dep_name##", textBox4.Text, false);
```

i have onther tag ##image## .

```
doc.SaveAs("C:\\tm0"+textBox1.Text+".docx");
```

Comment: what **is** the problem?

Comment: i don't know how to replace text  with image

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481188/find-and-replace-text-with-an-image-in-word-document) will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I done it.
I am loading a word document from file (a kind of template), then searching for specific text tags and replacing them.

The picture I want to insert is first saved as a temporary file.

```
DocX document = DocX.Load(filename);
string pictureFile = ... //"path and name of temp picture file, to include";

var docxImage = document.AddImage(pictureFile);
string rtag = "<<Tag.I.Want.To.Replace.Diagram>>";

var paragraphs = document.Paragraphs.Where(x => x.Text.Contains(rtag));
foreach (var paragraph in paragraphs)
{
    paragraph.InsertPicture(docxImage.CreatePicture(600, 600), 0);
    paragraph.ReplaceText(rtag, "");
}
```

Comment: What was wrong with OP code, I am not seeing an explanation? I only see a possible alternative solution without explanation...

Comment: it's work but i have another problem ... when add 2 images word file crashs

Comment: @HussenAlkunyali Then you need to open a new question on SO with you code for this problem